# TypeScript 0.9 Overload Is Callable

Tags: typescript

I have the following example of the issue. In TypeScript 0.9 I seem to be able to call the final signature of an overloaded method:

```
class Test {
    method(...names: string[]) : void;
    method(names: string[]) : void {

    }
}

var x= new Test();

x.method('One', 'Two', 'Three');
x.method(['One', 'Two', 'Three']);
```

In TypeScript 0.8.x you would have to specify a third signature, thus:

```
class Test {
    method(...names: string[]) : void;
    method(names: string[]) : void;
    method(names: any) : void {

    }
}

var x= new Test();

x.method('One', 'Two', 'Three');
x.method(['One', 'Two', 'Three']);
```

Shouldn't the final signature be hidden? (Because it is most likely to contain an over-generalised signature with `any` types etc).

Comment: what is the final signature?

Comment: The final signature is the one that has an implementation (i.e. not one that ends with a `;`). So in the last example, the final signature is `method(names: any) : void {` and all the rest are overloaded signatures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 0.8.x behavior is correct; we had a regression in 0.9 that's fixed in the develop branch now. Implementation signatures are indeed never visible.